# Resolving relative URI references with fragments in C#

Tags: c#, uri

I'm trying to deal with relative references that contain fragments. Per [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-4.1), this appears to be valid:

```
relative-ref  = relative-part [ "?" query ] [ "#" fragment ]
```

However every time I try and create a URI in C# with an included fragment, the fragment character is escaped and included in the path component:

```cs
using System;

namespace UriResolution
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var baseURI = new Uri(
                "/home/user/project-root/Base.item",
                UriKind.Absolute);
            var relative = new Uri("Relative.item#Fragment", UriKind.Relative);
            var directResolved = new Uri(baseURI, "Relative.item#Fragment");
            var joined = new Uri(baseURI, relative);
            Console.WriteLine($"Base: {baseURI}, Relative: {relative}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DirectResolved: {directResolved}, Fragment: {directResolved.Fragment}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Joined: {joined}, Fragment: {joined.Fragment}");
        }
    }
}
```

Yields

```
Base: file:///home/user/project-root/Base.item, Relative: Relative.item#Fragment
DirectResolved: file:///home/user/project-root/Relative.item%23Fragment, Fragment: 
Joined: file:///home/user/project-root/Relative.item%23Fragment, Fragment:
```

Is there some other standard library capability I should be using instead? Is there some third-party library considered de-facto cannon for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be a limitation of URIs constructed from non-URI file paths. Prepending `file://` to the path used by the base URI will allow things to be parsed as expected:

```
using System;

namespace UriResolution
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var baseURI = new Uri(
                "file:///home/user/project-root/Base.item",
                UriKind.Absolute);
            var relative = new Uri("Relative.item#Fragment", UriKind.Relative);
            var directResolved = new Uri(baseURI, "Relative.item#Fragment");
            var joined = new Uri(baseURI, relative);
            Console.WriteLine($"Base: {baseURI}, Relative: {relative}");
            Console.WriteLine($"DirectResolved: {directResolved}, Fragment: {directResolved.Fragment}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Joined: {joined}, Fragment: {joined.Fragment}");
        }
    }
}
```

Yields

```
Base: file:///home/user/project-root/Base.item, Relative: Relative.item#Fragment
DirectResolved: file:///home/user/project-root/Relative.item#Fragment, Fragment: #Fragment
Joined: file:///home/user/project-root/Relative.item#Fragment, Fragment: #Fragment
```